# Closure gets executed although its nil

Tags: swift

I have a dynamic variable called "data"
But currently the "data" variable is nil. However the following closure gets executed anyways?

```
var data = Dynamic<[PFUser]?>(nil)

if let data = data.value{
print("Data value \(data.value)")
return
}
```

Is there any solution for this problem?

Comment: you want to check what's in your Dynamic, not the Dynamic var itself. (I.e. you've made a new Dynamic that contains nil, you haven't assigned _nil_ to _data_)

Comment: i posted as an answer

Answer (score 0):

You want to check what's in your Dynamic, not the Dynamic var itself. (I.e. you've made a new Dynamic that contains nil, you haven't assigned nil to data)

As it is:

```
data ← Dynamic( nil )
```

You want

```
data ← nil
```

Try code like this:

```
var data:Dynamic<[PFUser]?>? = nil
```

Or this:

```
var data = Optional<Dynamic<[PFUser]?>> = nil
```

Now data is an optional containing *nil*

Comment: Thanks again. I tried your solution but I m getting error at other part of the code such as `cannot assign to property: 'value' is a get-only property`.

Comment: I don't know what Dynamic is

Comment: anyway that's a separate question

Comment: Dynamic variable is under the **Swift Bond Framework**. When the value of the variable changes, it causes the actions/label attached to it (i.e UILabel) changes based on the new value